# easy arrow as drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have spent hours trying to make the below arrow using drawables using all kind of rotations without any success it simply never looked like it:

[image: The insanely difficult arrow]

Is it even possible to make it using shape/layer-list, without using png?

*** EDIT ***

The closest I could get to the desired arrow was this. I could never put the lines to match and NOT to overlap:

[image: My best try]

Comment: `VectorDrawable` on Android 5.0+ should be able to handle this. There is [an official backport apparently in the works](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/vectordrawable/), and you can perhaps use [this library](https://github.com/telly/MrVector) in the meantime.

Comment: didnt understand you question.. please elaborate more.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use a png drawable?

Comment: @Squonk Yes, flexibility and size. I will need the arrow in 3 colors X states.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe this what you are looking for

> arrow.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-45">
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

in case you have edges not sticking you can add top and bottom to  elements so for first one add `<item android:bottom="5dp">` for second `<item android:top="4dp">`      ....

Comment: added edit which will make line ends to stick together

Comment: @Villen Melkumyan You have won the match! ;) Bounty in 2 days. I usually remember. In case that not, just ping me here.